# "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." in nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create an link scraper which worked so far. I only had problems when I was copying multiple lines, then it never stoped inserting these lines. So I wanted to split the mutliple lines into single lines but after creating the for loop which is iterating over the multilines I always get this error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

```
import pyperclip
import datetime


while True:
    with open("text.txt", "r+") as textfile:
        text = str(pyperclip.paste())
        liste = text.split("\r\n")

        for element in liste:
            for line in textfile:

                if element in line:
                    break
            else: 
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                textfile.write(str(now.day) + "." + str(now.month) + "." +
                               str(now.year) + " " + str(now. hour) + ":" +
                               str(now.minute) + " | ")
                textfile.write(element + "\n")
                textfile.close()
                print(element)
```

Comment: Uh, maybe you're getting that error because you're closing it: `textfile.close()`?

Comment: Don't call `textfile.close()` inside the loop.

Comment: oh well, yes you are right, thanks a lot

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Out of interest, from your experience on the site, why should this question be downvoted? Simply because it is simple or...

Comment: @JoeIddon I didn't downvote, but this question could've been avoided by being a little more sensible... 1) reading the docs to know what close does and not use it if you shouldn't, or 2) step through with a debugger and figure out what the issue is, or 3) research, this has been asked before, I guarantee it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Fair enough, but there are worse questions on the site which get upvoted

Comment: @JoeIddon Then it's our job as responsible denizens of the site to downvote such questions and voice our opinions, leaving constructive criticism on the post to educate others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the `error`! It says:

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

So clearly, you are trying to do something with a `file` that you have already `closed`! You are closing it on this line:

```
textfile.close()
```

and then continuing the `loop` and trying to do more operations on it. Therefore, to fix this, just remove that `line` and the `file` will be `closed` anyway due to the `with` statement.